# Why don't light-up runway numbers similar to runway lights?

Tags: runways, night-flying

I know that some airports have lights on the runway that can be controlled with the mic transmit button. Additionally, during night flight, runway lights help the pilot determine where the runway is located on the ground.

However, the runway numbers/letters are always indicated on the end of the runway, but do not light up. Why aren't the runway numbers made to light up? I'd think that at busy airports, this would help pilots determine the correct runway at night (ex. in the case of a "left"/"right" runway for a busy airport).

Comment: There are other ways to identify a runway, like the type of lighting, the approach itself and the heading on your own compass as you approach the runway.  But still...having the numbers lit on the runway would be nice.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to see the numbers until too late, you're already lined up on the wrong one.  When asking these kinds of questions, it's useful to ask 2 prior questions.  1.  What problem does it solve?  2.  What real benefit is gained and how often for the extra cost, complexity, maintenance, weight etc for the thing which is the object of the question?

Comment: @Simon: You can still go awround once you've lined up on the wrong wrunway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is fairly easy to determine which runway is the correct one by other means.

Runways are numbered based on their compass direction. The runway number will be the compass direction divided by 10 - for example, a runway with a direction of 150 degrees would be numbered 15.
This makes it possible to verify that you are using the correct runway by simply looking at your compass, to make sure the runway is pointing in the right direction. Even during day time in nice weather, this check is routinely performed before taking off by most pilots.

Runway identifiers for parallel runways are suffixed with an 'L' for the left runway and an 'R' for the right runway (from the pilot perspective). At airports with three parallel runways, the identifier of the middle one will be suffixed with 'C' for center.
When approaching an airport at night, the runways will - as you point out - be clearly lit. It is easy for the pilot to spot any parallel runways and make sure they are approaching the correct one, simply by observing the relative position of the runways.

During night or periods with degraded visibility, most traffic will make use of precision instrument approach systems, such as ILS, which will guide the plane precisely to the correct runway, without much risk for confusion.

On the ground, clear airport signage make it *nearly* impossible to mistake which runway you are on.

In addition, at busy airports with multiple runways, air traffic control service is likely to be provided. Air traffic controllers will monitor all aircraft movements on the maneuvering area and in the vicinity of the aerodrome, and will quickly be able to notify any pilot who is about to use a wrong runway.

Another point is that lighted runway numbers would probably be pretty ineffecient, as the relatively small size of runway numbers would make it impossible to read them from a distance, even if they were lit. A pilot approaching a wrong runway would notice this too late to be able to make corrections, and would have to perform a missed approach. Granted, doing so would in many cases be better than landing on the wrong runway.

Comment: There are airports, like KATL that has 5 parallel runways, all of which are oriented 90°/270°. They number them 8/26 L and R. 9/27 L and R, and 10/28. Doesn't seem like it would be too difficult to line up on the wrong one

Comment: @TomMcW Indeed, but I think the last half of my answer still applies in that case :)

Comment: @J.Hougaard Thanks! As a VFR (student) pilot, I have no experience flying at night, and no ILS experience. I guess my question was also, "then why do things like [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3381878/EasyJet-plane-lands-wrong-runway-Pisa-airport.html) happen?", given the number of hours / experience that EasyJet pilot must have had.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Agreed. It makes me wonder if they clear flights for visual approaches at night. If you're fiddle in to the ILS you pretty much can't be off, but with so many runways pointed at them it seems like it might be a problem visually

Comment: @TomMcW I have no idea what the local procedures at Atlanta are like, but with a proper approach briefing and by studying the relevant charts, an aircrew should have no major issues identifying the correct runway to approach visually, regardless of whether it is day or night

Comment: @TomMcW At least in the case of Atlanta, picking out the right runway visually isn't really a problem. The 8's and 9's are separated by the busiest airport passenger terminal complex in the world, so it's pretty easy to tell them apart in VFR conditions. 10 is also separated quite a bit with Interstate 285 and a big cargo terminal separating it from the 9s. Also, if there's not a plane (or several planes) in front of you, that's a good sign you're lined up on the wrong runway, as that pretty much never happens at ATL. Also, if you see departures from a runway, don't land there.

Comment: @reirab I read an FAA document once about parallel runway use. If you use simultaneous parallel runways within a particular distance ILS is required. (It was an old paper, before RNAV) I've noticed from listening to KMEM ATC during the heavy time that they never clear visual on rwys 18/36 LRC but for rwy 27, as soon as the pilot announces airport in sight they clear them visual.

Comment: @TomMcW That makes sense, though I suspect that's also partially due to the need to maintain separation between aircraft on simultaneous approaches to different parallel runways.

Comment: @reirab It's definitely for separation. But it probably has a secondary effect of ensuring runway id. Most of the time the ATC would be hard-pressed to tell on radar which of two parallel runways the pilot is looking at.

Comment: Runway edge lights are not flush with the concrete, but stick up on posts.  To have lit runway numbers, the lights would need to be flush with the runway rather than on posts, would need to survive being rolled over or even landed on, and would still need to be visible even after long periods of such abuse.  Also, resurfacing the runway becomes a lot harder.

Comment: @WayneConrad -- it's no different a problem than TDZ/CL lighting, really.